# Timeout logout (JavaScript, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, logout

I tryed to use this code to auto logout after 15 mins.
But this doesnt work properly. I leave my comp for 15mins, but nothing happend. It remains logged in.

But on the other hand, if i try shorter time, for an example 5s it works perfect...after 5s it logged me off.

I don't know, where is problem/bug?

```
var int=self.setInterval(setLastAction,1000);

function setLastAction(){
    var lastAction = new Date();    
    var baz = new Date();
    baz.setTime(lastAction.getTime() - firstAction.getTime());
    baz = baz.getSeconds();

    if(baz >= (15*60)){
         logOut();      
    }
}

$(document).mousemove(function(){
    firstAction = new Date();
});
```

Comment: here is a timer script which is tested perfectly: http://blog.webtech11.com/2012/07/29/countdown-timer-with-javascript.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the seconds from a `Date` object, using [`getSeconds()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getSeconds), which will *always* return an integer between `0` and `59`. Compare the difference between the times instead of creating a new `Date` object:

```
var secondsBetween = (lastAction.getTime() - firstAction.getTime()) / 1000;
if (secondsBetween >= (15 * 60)) {
     logOut();      
}
```